# react one state variable depends on multiple other states variables

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I am coming from angular world. And I am still kinda new to react.

One question that I encountered is that:

In angular, we have `$watch` to watch one scope variables to change and update other variables. like watch B,C,D, and change of B,C,D will affect variable A

In react, I am trying to do the same thing. However, I am calling to `setState(B,callbackB)` to update A. A has a `setState` that has an impact in render

It seems like doing such works correctly for variable B. However, updating A will occur in next render cycle. And `this.forceUpdate()` doesn't seems work.

Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my example code, I think I found an answer already.

https://jsfiddle.net/yoyohoho/Lo58kgfq/1/

in the example code in jsfiddle. The input field is a required field.

And the button should be disabled if there is nothing in the field.

The problem is that if you type something and you erase it, **button is still active, until you type in 1 more key, which is next cycle.**

I use input1Err to determine if formError should be disabled in checkErr()

```
checkErr(){
    if(this.state.input1Err == false){
        this.setState({formErr: false });
    }else{
        this.setState({formErr: true });
    }
}
```

This is the reason that why the view change happen in next cycle. **Because setState is asynchronous**

I was using this.state.input1Err to determine formErr, which may yet be changed before the if statement there.

So I changed to the following closure, which solves my issue.

```
checkErr(){
  const self = this;
  (function(j){setTimeout(function(){
    if(self.state.input1Err == false){
      self.setState({formErr: false });
    }else{
      self.setState({formErr: true });
    }
  },10)})(self);
}
```

This seems be a quick fix. However, what if there is ajax call and hooked up to state.input1Err. Is there a way I can watch this variable, so when it changes **complete**, I can have some sort of callback?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

An example would help clarify your situation, but depending on what "updating A" entails, you could move it to your render function. E.g.

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  handleUpdate(B) {
    this.setState({B})
  }

  computeAFromB(B) {
    ...
    return A
  }

  render() {
    const A = this.computeAFromB(this.state.B)

    return <div>{A}</div>
  }
}
```

When transitioning from Angular to React, it's important to keep in mind that `scope !== state`. This may be helpful: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely on setState to update instantly. Try passing the new value explicitly to setState A.